# php how to push array onto an array of arrays

Tags: php, arrays

Using the following code:

```
 $masterInclude[$cnt]  = $incX[$j];           
 array_push($masterInclude[$cnt],$incY[$i]);

$cnt = 63;
$incX[$j]=

[0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-04-28
            [usr] => 1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-05-15
            [usr] => 1
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-06-20
            [usr] => 1
        )
```

and $incY[$i] =

```
[0] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2016-05-15
                    [usr] => 90
                )
```

I'm getting the following output:

```
[63] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [date] => 2016-04-28
                [usr] => 1
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [date] => 2016-05-15
                [usr] => 1
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [date] => 2016-06-20
                [usr] => 1
            ) 
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [date] => 2016-05-15
                        [usr] => 90
                    )                   
            )

    )

    )
```

but would like to get:

```
[63] => Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-04-28
            [usr] => 1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-05-15
            [usr] => 1
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-06-20
            [usr] => 1
        ) 
    [3] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-05-15
            [usr] => 90
        )    


  )
 )
```

Anant suggested using:

```
$incX[$j][]=$incY[$i];
```

but that produces:

```
[63] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [date] => 2016-04-28
                [usr] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [date] => 2016-05-15
                [usr] => 1
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [date] => 2016-06-20
                [usr] => 1
            )



        [3] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [date] => 2016-06-20
                        [usr] => 90
                    )

            )
```

Comment: I think you want `$masterInclude[$cnt][] = $incY[$i];` but i'm not sure becuase you've not shared what $cnt is or what the difference is between `$incY[$j]` and `$incX[$i]`

Comment: i tried $masterInclude[$cnt][] = $incY[$i] but it didn't work and array_push($masterInclude[$cnt],$incY[$i]); is what i'm doing now in the originbal question, and obviously that doesn't work either

Comment: @Anant, that doesn't work

Comment: @anant, that's still not working correctly.

Comment: @DCR Oh man if you look you will get it easily `$incX[$j][] = $incY[$i][0]; $masterInclude[$cnt] = $incX[$j];`

Comment: Anant, this almost works but only adds the first object of $incY[$i].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)?

or

```
array_push($masterInclude,$incY[$i]);
```

Can't tell for sure without the rest of the code loop.

Comment: array_merge is what I needed.  Thanks so much for your help

Answer (score -1):

Your $incX[$j] is an Array of Arrays:
Array (
  [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-04-28
            [usr] => 1
        )
  [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-05-15
            [usr] => 1
        )
  [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-06-20
            [usr] => 1
        )
)

so my suggestion is use the array_push against $incX[$j] like so:
array_push($incX[$j], $incY[$i])